# How to open a url/webpage in codeception acceptance testing?

Tags: testing, codeception, acceptance

**Testing framework:** [Codeception](http://codeception.com/)

How to open a url/webpage in codeception acceptance testing ?

Answer (score 2):

You can open an url directly by method: amOnPage

[PHP-Browser](http://codeception.com/docs/03-AcceptanceTests#PHP-Browser)

If you are using Selenium you can see here: [WebDriver](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#amOnPage)

Comment: It's not working for me anyways please check my codeception config file and acceptance test code file.

config: http://pastebin.com/hk0iJ1ib
code: http://pastebin.com/hHguqFKT

Comment: I think, you have a problem with the config. Try to use this config: http://pastebin.com/naaF6Ekx

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works, anyway there is a good example for this.http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/acceptance-testing-with-codeception--net-36337

Answer (score 2):

You should have a webdriver enabled in your config for the suite you are using. Usually PhantomJS or Selenium for acceptance testing. You should also set a base URL. i.e.:

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester 
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
            url: 'http://localhost/'
            browser: phantomjs
```

There are two commands:

amOnPage($page) - appends $page to URL and opens

amOnUrl($URL) - opens $URL directly

So with the above config:

```
$I->amOnPage("works"); //opens http://localhost/works
$I->amOnPage("http://localhost/dontwork"); //error!
$I->amOnUrl("http://localhost/works"); //opens http://localhost/works
```